# Calculate median of dictionary values inside list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm looking to calculate the **median** of "score" (a dictionary value) inside a list.

```
my_dict = {"John": [{"class": "math", "score": 100, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 85, "year": 2015}, {"class": "science", "score": 90, "year": 2015}], 
"Timmy": [{"class": "math", "score": 87, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 91, "year": 2015}], 
"Sally":[{"class": "math", "score": 95, "year": 2014}]}
```

The output would look like:

```
new_dict = {"John": 90, "Timmy": 89, "Sally": 95}
```

I figured I need to sort my_dict based on score and then calculate the median value. Can't quite figure out either step without using an exterior package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! New to Python.

Comment: You don't have to sort "my_dict" but for each value (list) in "my_dict" you must extract the "score"s (by iterating over the list items) in a new list, sort that and retrieve the median for one key in "my_dict". Try to do this yourself first and show your code as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the median from [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html).

```
from statistics import median

my_dict = {"John": [{"class": "math", "score": 100, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 85, "year": 2015}, {"class": "science", "score": 90, "year": 2015}], 
"Timmy": [{"class": "math", "score": 87, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 91, "year": 2015}], 
"Sally":[{"class": "math", "score": 95, "year": 2014}]}

new_dict = {}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
  m = []
  for l in v:
    m.append(l["score"])
  new_dict[k] = median(m)

print(new_dict)
```

---

If you don't want to use a package and write your own function, you can call this:

```
def median(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    s = sorted(lst)
    return (sum(s[n//2-1:n//2+1])/2.0, s[n//2])[n % 2] if n else None
```

Comment: `statistics` is not "external package"

Answer (score 2):

One liner using [median](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) and dict comprehension

```
from statistics import median 
{k:median([v.get('score',0) for v in my_dict[k]]) for k in my_dict.keys()}
```

Output:

```
{'John': 90, 'Timmy': 89.0, 'Sally': 95}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {"John": [{"class": "math", "score": 100, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 85, "year": 2015}, {"class": "science", "score": 90, "year": 2015}], 
"Timmy": [{"class": "math", "score": 87, "year": 2014}, {"class": "english", "score": 91, "year": 2015}], 
"Sally":[{"class": "math", "score": 95, "year": 2014}]}

import numpy as np
medians = {}
for k in my_dict.keys():
    ls = []
    for d in my_dict[k]:
        ls.append(d['score'])
    medians[k] = np.median(ls)

print(medians)
```

output:

```
{'Sally': 95.0, 'Timmy': 89.0, 'John': 90.0}
```

You can just use numpy.median to calculate the median.